# optimize query with group by and sum

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

the following query executes 8 seconds

```
SELECT `currency`, sum(amount) as amount
FROM `p_transactions`
WHERE `member_id` = 2051
AND `transaction_type` = 'debit'
AND `transaction_status` = 12
GROUP BY `currency`
```

but if remove GROUP BY `currency` part it shorts up to 2 seconds. Is there some way to speed up this query?

Indexes are composite (member_id, transaction_type, transaction_status).

Comment: How many rows match the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: 1 row currently

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about the query?

Comment: If there's only 1 row, I can't believe it takes more than a fraction of a second in either form.

Comment: @Barmar But with group by its 6 rows.

Comment: That's not possible. `GROUP BY` can't create more rows in the result than there are in the table. It combines multiple rows from the table, it doesn't expand them. Did you misunderstand my question?

Comment: What is the value of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `p_transactions`
WHERE `member_id` = 2051
AND `transaction_type` = 'debit'
AND `transaction_status` = 12 -- It is probably more than "1" or "6", hence the original query may take a while to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your index to:

```
(member_id, transaction_type, transaction_status, currency)
```

Comment: And tack on `amount` (_on the end_) to make the index "covering".